# what to do if i have to get values of YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES and MONTH_CHOICES in same field called 'new_field'

Tags: django, django-admin

```
YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
    ('FR', ('Freshman')),
    ('SO', ('Sophomore')),
    ('JR', ('Junior')),
    ('SR', ('Senior')),
    ('GR', ('Graduate')),)

MONTH_CHOICES = (
    ('JAN', ('January')),
    ('FEB', ('February')),
    ('MAR', ('March')),
    ....
    ('DEC', ('December')),
)
```

new_field = ChoiceArrayField(base_field=models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=(YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES, MONTH_CHOICES)), default=CallableList([]), blank=True)

Comment: `choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES + MONTH_CHOICES`?

Comment: It is an array of choices, so you need to combine the two tuples like the other commenter said.  Also, this is a `django` question, not a `django-rest-framework` question.